# To get product collections by some range of ids in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to update all product price by specific percentage from current price.I got the following line of code update price by percentage wise

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('price');
 foreach ($products as $product) {

 $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.03);
 $product->save();
 echo $product->getId()."updated Sucess";
 }
```

Its working well. But it will take **so much time to complete** the above process because we have a lot of products in our store. Some times it will return **time out error** too. So i want to perform this above operation by **split those product collections** like if we have **1000 products**, do this operation by like below

```
Collect 1st 100 products from product collections
Update price of those products
Then collect next 100 products
Update price of those products
```

Anybody have an idea to get product collections by some range of ids?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$_productCOllection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
    'from' => $startPrOID,
    'to' => $EndPrOID
    ))
    ->load();
```

Comment: Thank you for you immediate response. Its working well, Thank you so much. It have some tiny mistakes on product collections. filter product by product id, not by price!

Comment: Just change price to entity_id

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using magento (or any other framework, it's better to directly query the database instead of using the system in place.

Using this :

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = ‘price’
```

You'll get your `price` attribute `id`.

Then using this :

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` 
    WHERE `attribute_id` = [above id] and `store_id` = [id of your store]
```

You'll get all your prices for a given store (which you can update using a simple MySQL `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. and also i want to set price for specific store only. can i select store by this way?

Comment: If I recall well there is a `store_id` column in `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, so answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have run your code too. Its also working well in my local server. But i have fear to edit Db directly. @AmitBera answer also working fine with in my frame work. Thank you yar!